# Fedora 21 adb keep saying error: device not found

Tags: android, adb, fedora

I already installed adbtools on my machine, and I already create file:
/etc/udev/rules.d/50-android.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="1004", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
```

but when I try to run `adb shell`, it keep saying `error: device not found`, `adb status-window` shows `State: unknown`, I already enable USBdebugging on my LG G3-d859.

So, how can I fix it? Thank you

Comment: I also try run adb tool under root user and normal user, still not working.I already root my phone

Comment: read the part about modifying `adb_usb.ini`: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html

Comment: @AlexP. it is still not working too, but thank you

Answer (score 2):

I have an LGD851, had the same problem, put the USB mode on the phone into PTP instead of MTP.

Comment: I have an LG G3 and change from MTP to PTP solved te problem to me.
Fedora 21 64 bits